# using gluPerspective in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I was doing my OpenGL program and I happen to have a problem, 
can you find what is the matter with it?

It rotates a plane with the y axis as the centre 
when I am using `glOrtho` it is working fine, but `gluPerspective` it is not.

There is some problem with the `gluPerspective` because when I change the angle to 0 I can just see something but not the whole thing. But when I change it to 45. Nothing comes on the screen and I'm not getting the clue about the near and far values.

```
 #include iostream  
 #include "Xlib.h"  
 #include "gl.h"  
 #include "glu.h"  
 #include "glut.h"  
 #include math.h  
void setupRC()  
{  
    glClearColor(1,0,0,1);  
    glColor3f(0,0,0);  
}  
void timerfunc(int value)  
{  
    glutPostRedisplay();  
    glutTimerFunc(1, timerfunc ,1);  
}  
void RenderScene()   
{  
    glColor3f(0,0,0);  
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);  
    static GLfloat rot = 0.0f,x =0.0f , y=1.0f , z=0.0f;  
    rot++;  
    glPushMatrix();  

    glRotatef(rot,0.0,1.0,0.0);  
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);  
        glVertex3i(1,-1,0);  
        glVertex3i(1,1,0);  
        glVertex3i(-1,1,0);  
        glVertex3i(-1,-1,0);  
        glVertex3i(1,-1,0);  

    glEnd();  
    glPopMatrix();  
    if (rot == 360)  
        rot = 0;  
    glutSwapBuffers();  
}  
void ChangeSize(GLint w, GLint h)  
{  
    if(h==0)  
        h = 1;  
    GLfloat aspectratio = (GLfloat)w/(GLfloat)h;  

    glViewport(0,0,w,h);  
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);  
    glLoadIdentity();  
    gluPerspective(45.0f, aspectratio, 1,1000);  
    /*if(w <= h)  
        glOrtho(-100,100,-100/aspectratio, 100/aspectratio, 1,-1);  
    else   
        glOrtho(-100*aspectratio, 100*aspectratio , -100,100,1,-1);*/  
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);  
    glLoadIdentity();  

}  

int main(int argc , char **argv)  
{  
    glutInit(&argc, argv);  
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);  
    glutInitWindowSize(800,600);  
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);  
    glutCreateWindow("chelsea");  
    glutTimerFunc(1, timerfunc , 1);  
    setupRC();  
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);  
    glutReshapeFunc(ChangeSize);  
    glutMainLoop();  

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Perhaps create a more descriptive title?

Comment: Using complete words and punctuation makes your question easier to read and thus more lightly to get an answer.

Comment: oh k. wl see to that.
Thanks for the feedback

Comment: stackoverflow is supposed to check the right answer, if it fits to you.

Answer (score 9):

You problem is: **your polygon and your camera are at the same coordinates**. (The polygon is not *in front* of the camera, it is *on* it.)

1. When the polygon is in its initial position, it is exactly aligned with the camera which cannot see it;
2. when it begins rotating, a part of it goes in front of the camera, but it is too close to be displayed.

However, setting the `fovy` to 0° when building your perspective matrix yields a (really) wide angle camera, which is able to see (really) close objects -- explaining why you can see something, "but not the whole thing".

If you want to be able to see "the whole thing" with `fovy=45`, move your polygon away from the camera by applying a negative translation along the Z axis:

```
void RenderScene()
{
    ...
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.,0.,-10.); // Move away from camera
    glRotatef(rot,0.0,1.0,0.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        ...
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you very very much 
Now i understand every thing and its been a real help.
Thank you